# Get all parent IDs without CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a query that returns all parent ids from a table which has simple structure of just `child_id` and `parent_id` by given `child_id`.

However, all of this business happens within a larger query which has some outer applies which generate the `child_id` in question so if I'm using CTE then I'm not able to pass the input parameters for the CTE itself. The larger query is something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table
OUTER APPLY (some query here that generates as child id) AS generated_child_id
WHERE some_table.id IN (LIST_OF_ALL_PARENTS_OF_CHILD_ID_PLUS_CHILD_ID_ITSELF)
```

If I use a CTE which selects the parent ids then the `generated_child_id` is not available in it which is the whole point. I either need another approach or somehow I need to define the CTE within the `WHERE` clause which I have no idea how to do.

Comment: Can you please show some sample data and desired result?  I can't follow your description of what you're trying to do, or why you think a CTE won't work for you.

Comment: I'm with @Siyual here. How is your select generating child ID values and why are you generating ID values in a select? And what does that have to do with a CTE?

Comment: Bear in mind - a CTE isn't a *separate* query - it's optimized as part of the whole query. So the CTE could generate, for *every* child id all possible parent ids. When you later select and filter from that CTE then the system *should* be able to push the filtering down so that it *doesn't* literally then generate the set of all child ids and their parents.

Answer (score 0):

A CTE really can be treated "as if" the thing is a view/table during your query. You can make the CTE definition thorough and then apply filters when querying it, and those filters should be pushed down as far as possible as they're applied.

For instance, I created a table containing ~1 million rows using the following query:

```
create table T (ParentID int not null, ChildID int not null)
;With Numbers as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY so1.object_id) as n
    from sys.objects so1
    cross join sys.objects so2
    cross join sys.objects so3
)
insert into T(ParentID,ChildID)
select n1.n,n2.n
from Numbers n1
inner join
Numbers n2
    on
        n1.n = n2.n - 1
create index IX_Parent_Child on T(ParentID,ChildID)
create index IX_Child_Parent on T(ChildID,ParentID)
```

This is a particularly nasty parent/child setup since it's all one long chain and so the last child is ultimately related to the very first parent via every other row.

Then I query it, using a CTE:

```
;With Ancestors as (
    select ParentID as AncestorID, ChildID
    from T
    union all
    select t.ParentID,a.ChildID
    from
        Ancestors a
            inner join
        T t
            on
                a.AncestorID = t.ChildID
)
select
    AncestorID
from
    (select 1) t(t)
        cross apply
    (select 15) as u(ChildID)
        cross apply
    (select AncestorID from Ancestors where ChildID = u.ChildID) v
```

And examine the query plan. At no point in the plan do ~1 million rows get materialized - just the 13/14 rows required to *actually* complete the query.

So, write a generic CTE across all children and then query/filter from it as you would any other table/view - and trust the optimizer to do the right thing.